# how to eliminate unneeded record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following result set:

```
firstname   lastname    scheduled                 posted          EventAdded
Student      One    2014-04-28 00:00:00.000 2014-04-28 12:02:07.037 NULL
Student      One    2014-04-28 00:00:00.000 2014-04-28 12:02:07.037 later
OtherKid     Two    2014-04-28 00:00:00.000 2014-04-28 21:09:33.457 NULL
```

How do I eliminate the first record?

If a student has many EventAddeds - we only want the one where EventAdded is not null.
If a student has many EventAddeds that are not null - we want any record where EventAdded is not null.
If a student only has one record (regardless of EventAdded being null) - we want the record.

The result we want is:

```
firstname   lastname    scheduled                 posted          EventAdded
Student      One    2014-04-28 00:00:00.000 2014-04-28 12:02:07.037 later
OtherKid     Two    2014-04-28 00:00:00.000 2014-04-28 21:09:33.457 NULL
```

We've tried more things than we can list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this for a query, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select firstname, lastname, scheduled, posted, eventadded
from (select rs.*,
             row_number() over (partition by firstname, lastname
                                order by (case when eventadded is not null then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from ResultSet rs
     ) rs
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an old server (without row_number(), etc.)

```
select T.*  -- replace by delete of course to whack 'em
from tab1 T
where exists (select * from tab1 TIN where 
    (TIN.lastname = T.lastname 
     and TIN.FirstName = T.FirstName and TIN.EventAdded is not null))
and T.EventAdded is null
```

Comment: We tried almost exactly this so many times but never got the syntax just right. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I saw that the first answer helped you after I posted this. Results should be the same, but if you do this a lot, this might be faster as the if exists test might avoid a little work (retrieving all of the rows and ordering them). I have a customer that still has lots of Sql2K servers, so I am used to accommodating the old ways.